# I got exception: The type initializer for 'mws.Options_DB' threw an exception. what does it mean?

Tags: c#

What could be the problem ? The exception happen each time the same exception.
This is the line that throw the exception when i click a button and call it:

```
public void Save()
        {
            Options_DB.Set_Points_Coordinates_List(Point_X);
        }
```

The Point_X is a List of type Float

Cant figure out how ot fix the problem.

I have in Form1 a button click event where i call there the function above in another class: Save()

I used a breakpoint on it when its doing the line in the Save() function its going ot the Options_DB class and doing in the top of it:

```
static List<float> Points_Coordinates;
        static string settings_dir;
        static string settings_file;
        static OptionsFile setting_file;
        static string path_settings;
        static string path_exe;

        static Options_DB()
        {
            // ---  O P E N N I N G   S E T T I N G   F I L E   
            //t = voices_volume_trackbar.ToString();
            path_exe = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath);
            path_settings = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath);
            settings_file = "\\settings.txt";
            settings_dir = path_settings + @"\settings";
            setting_file = new OptionsFile(settings_dir + settings_file);
```

When its getting to the line: `setting_file = new OptionsFile(settings_dir + settings_file);` its getting to the OptionsFile class and there its trying to create the directory and file in the exception:

```
string path_exe;
        string temp_settings_file;
        string temp_settings_dir;
        string Options_File;
        StreamWriter sw;
        StreamReader sr;

/*----------------------------------------------------------
 * Function     : OptionsFile
 * Description  : Constructor
 * Parameters   : file_name is the name of the file to use
 * Return       : none
 * --------------------------------------------------------*/
    public OptionsFile(string settings)
    {

        if (File.Exists(settings))
        {

        }
        else
        {
        FileStream fs=File.Create(settings);
```

But once the breakpoint is on the line File.Create(settings); and i see that settings containing the path and file name instead of creating them its jumping back to the Save() function to the line inside there and then throw the exception.

Why its jumping to the Save() and not creating the path and file ?

Comment: Did you notice the `Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Chocolade\AppData\Local\AnimationEditor\AnimationEditor\settings\settings.txt'` in the InnerException?

Answer (score 0):

That exception means that some static member of that type could not be initialized or the static constructor for that type failed. Check those.

Your stacktrace clearly indicates that the problem is

> at mws.Options_DB..cctor() in D:\C-Sharp\AnimationEditor\AnimationEditor\Options_DB.cs:line 30

.cctor() is the static constructor.